# Rails 4 postgres bug - cannot create database because the pg gem "is missing", but it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I use rails edge (4.0) and when executing:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

I get

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
```

I do have "gem pg" in my Gemfile and I have run bundle install...

what could be the reason for this?

thank you

Comment: Can you try `require 'pg'` in `rails console`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an old version of pg gem (0.9.0), newer versions work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

For me, works without user/pass, and using `host` settings on `config/database.yml`

```
defatul: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  host: localhost
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_test
```