# Rails application doesn't recognize postgres gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I installed Rails 4 on my Windows 8 system, and the DevKit, and installed the **pg** (PostgreSQL) gem.

```
> gem install pg
...
Successfully installed pg-0.16.0-x64-mingw32
```

I created a new rails application:

```
> rails new blog -d postgresql
```

But when I start rails server

```
> cd blog
> rails server
```

and navigate to the `localhost:3000` in my browser, I see this error:

`` Gem::LoadError
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile. ``

My Gemfile includes these lines:

```
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
```

Additionally, if I do

```
bundle install
```

**pg** is not listed in the output.

If I do

```
require 'pg'
```

in the Ruby console I get

```
=> true
```

This question is very similar to

[Rails 4 postgres bug - cannot create database because the pg gem "is missing", but it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958219/rails-4-postgres-bug-cannot-create-database-because-the-pg-gem-is-missing-b)

but in that case the questioner realized he was using an older version of the pg gem. I have the version that was installed with `gem install pg`, which I assume is the most recent one.

Can anyone provide some troubleshooting guidance?

**Update:**

From the comment by @vinodadhikary I tried `bundle update pg`

which returned

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
...
Your bundle is updated!
```

without mentioning pg.

I then tried `bundle show pg`, which returned

```
Could not find gem 'pg'.
Did you mean pg?
```

I tried running the server again, and received the same error.

**Update 2**

I have my `config\database.yml` file configured per my existing postgres database, like

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rails_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
  port: 5433
```

and likewise for **test** and **production**.
Thanks Artiwarah Damrongchai for suggesting that.

Comment: Troubleshooting: try `bundle update pg` and check `bundle show pg`

Comment: Thanks vinodadhikary, I tried that and edited the question with an **update** of the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some help from [Andy Henson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432773/andy-henson) on #RubyOnRails IRC I was able to solve this issue, or at least work around it.

It seems like the issue may be with the way **bundler** identifies 32 and 64bit versions of the minGW build environment provided by DevKit. There's an outstanding bug here that looks relevant:

https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2356

But I was able to work around it by switching from using 64bit everything to using 32bit everything. Here are my steps:

I uninstalled 64bit Ruby. Then from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ I installed

- rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247.exe
- DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

Then I installed a 32bit version of postgres to C:\PostgreSQL\9.2

Then I installed the pg gem using

```
subst X: "C:\PostgreSQL\9.2"
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=X:
subst X: /D
```

(The `subst` command was overkill in this case, because there were no spaces in the postgres path, but it's a good trick to know for other situations.)

Then in my application host directory I ran `rails new blog -d postgresql`, and edited my `conf\database.yml` file per my postgres settings. This seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to config your database.yml file like this:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_database
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Thanks Artiwarah, I did indeed configure my `database.yml` file per my existing postgres database. I have updated my question to reflect that.